# Windows 7 wifi / ethernet driver for Asus X551CA Notebook

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, wifi-driver

I bought a notebook **Asus X551CA**. I installed Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, but when I went to download official drivers for Asus, I can download drivers only for Windows 8.

I installed Windows 7 and it works, *except for the wifi and ethernet driver*. 
I need to know that if I could resolve this problem installing driver for windows 7 of another series of Asus Notebook.

i don't want W8. I need W7.

Any suggests ?

Comment: have you tried to install the Win8 drivers? If yes, what happens?

Comment: Asus give me the drivers for windows 8, but when I insert cd an error message tell me "This drivers are not compatible with this OS", obv.

Comment: don't use the installer. Update/Install the drivers with the help of the device manager: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html

Comment: I discovered the chipset of my notebook are `Intel HM70 EXPRESS`
( http://tinyurl.com/papuzbt ).
I installed it and now the bus PCI and LAN work, but it doesn't recognize the Wifi again (missing drivers).

I MUST find that drivers, but I have no idea where!

Comment: this is the chipset. Go into the device manager, look at the properties and look for the hardware ID. Now go to a PCI database and look what device it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this article from Google because I searched for the same drivers. The information wasn't very helpful but at the end of the day I found the drivers and decided to share :)

These guys provide all drivers needed www.drp.su/drivers/notebooks/?v=ASUS&m=X551CA&id=195955&l=en

In case you are suspicious about the site above as I was -- you can download the drivers from manufacturers' sites

**LAN (Realtek)** http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

**WLAN (Atheros)** http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=61&system=5

Comment: Nice to see someone who knows how to get drivers from the chip manufacturer, instead of relying on the computer manufacturer or some third-party utility.

Answer (score 1):

This Model has the same hardware, and all the Windows 7 drivers.

[Here](http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/S46CA/#support)

Tested on an x551 - all drivers are working.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

I got the necessary drivers here: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=S46CA

The WLAN was the Atheros one.